# Yii2 currency format : difference between localhost and server

Tags: php, debian, yii2, locale, currency-formatting

I have PHP5/Yii2 application deployed on Nginx with i18n in place.
I have DEV and PROD servers both running Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u2 x86_64.

Yii configuration is repo-synced, envirnoment specific settings in 
main-local.php do not have anything to do with localization.

This line:
Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($invoiceLine->amount,$invoice->currency);
gives different result in DEV and PROD:
DEV: 100,00 €
PROD: EUR 100,00

I cannot find what setting would make PROD behave the same way as DEV. I do not want any solution that formats amount explicitly in yii code. I just want to know what I must do to have the same configuration on both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means you need to enable PHP internationalization extension (aka `intl`) on your prod server : http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Read more about [`\yii\i18n\Formatter::asCurrency()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asCurrency()-detail) :

> This function does not require the PHP intl extension to be installed to work, but it is highly recommended to install it to get good formatting results.

Read more about [PHP internationalization extension installation](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

For example, to install it on Debian :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Don't forget to restart your web server after.

Comment: Bullseye! The install solved my issue:  
`sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

Answer (score 0):

Check your [LC_* settings](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale). Maybe you're missing a locale on one of the systems. You could try installing the `locales-all` package on both systems to not have trouble related to missing locales